# Error in Google Cloud Shell Commands while working on the lab (Securing Google Cloud with CFT Scorecard)

Tags: gcloud, bucket, google-cloud-shell

I am working in a GCP lab (Securing Google Cloud with CFT Scorecard). All instructions for the lab are given.
First I have to run the following two commands to set environment variables

```
export GOOGLE_PROJECT=$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID
export CAI_BUCKET_NAME=cai-$GOOGLE_PROJECT
```

In the second command given above I don't know what to replace with my own credentials? May be that is the reason I am getting error.

Now I have to enable the "cloudasset.googleapis.com" gcloud service. For this they gave the following command.

```
gcloud services enable cloudasset.googleapis.com \
--project $GOOGLE_PROJECT
```

Error for this is given in the screeshot attached herewith:
[Error in the serviec enabling command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slvOw.png)
Next step is to clone the policy: The given command for that is:

```
git clone https://github.com/forseti-security/policy-library.git
```

After that they said: "You realize Policy Library enforces policies that are located in the policy-library/policies/constraints folder, in which case you can copy a sample policy from the samples directory into the constraints directory".
and gave this command:

```
cp policy-library/samples/storage_blacklist_public.yaml policy-library/policies/constraints/
```

On running this command I received this:
[error on running the directory command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpncq.png)

Finally they said "Create the bucket that will hold the data that Cloud Asset Inventory (CAI) will export" and gave the following command:

```
gsutil mb -l us-central1 -p $GOOGLE_PROJECT gs://$CAI_BUCKET_NAME
```

I am confused in where to replace my own credentials like in the place of project_Id I wrote my own project id.
Also I don't know these errors are ocurring. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to access the tutorial.

What happens if you run the following:

```sh
echo ${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}
```

I suspect you'll get an empty result because I think this environment variable isn't actually set.

I think it should be:

```sh
 echo ${DEVSHELL_GCLOUD_CONFIG}
```

Does that return a result?

If so, perhaps try using that variable instead:

```sh
export GOOGLE_PROJECT=${DEVSHELL_GCLOUD_CONFIG}
export CAI_BUCKET_NAME=cai-${GOOGLE_PROJECT}
```

It's not entirely clear to me why this tutorial is using this approach but, if the above works, it may get you further along.

We're you asked to create a Google Cloud Platform project?

Comment: I am asked on qwiklabs

Comment: DazWikin this isn't solved my problem I am attaching the complete tutorial below in answer. Kindly run the commands and inform me how can I remove these errors.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [shared error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slvOw.png), this seems to be because your env variable `GOOGLE_PROJECT` is not set. You can verify it by using `echo $GOOGLE_PROJECT` and seeing whether it returns the project ID or not. You could also use `echo $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID`. If that returns the project ID and the former doesn't, it means that you didn't export the variable as stated at the beginning.

If the problem is that `GOOGLE_PROJECT` doesn't have any value, there are different approaches on how to solve it.

1. Set the env variable as you explained at the beginning. Obviously this will only work if the variable `DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID` is also set.

   ```
   export GOOGLE_PROJECT=$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID
   ```
2. Manually set the project ID into that variable. This is far from ideal because in Qwiklabs they create a new temporal project on every lab, so this would've only worked if you were still on that project. The project ID can be seen on both of your shared screenshots.

   ```
   export GOOGLE_PROJECT=qwiklabs-gcp-03-c6e1787dc09e
   ```
3. Avoid using the argument `--project`. According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable), the aforementioned argument is optional and if none is used the command will take the one by default, which will be on the configuration settings. You can get the current project by using this:

   ```
    gcloud config get-value project
   ```

   If the previous command matches the project ID you want to use, you can simply issue the following command:

   ```
    gcloud services enable cloudasset.googleapis.com
   ```

   Notice that the project ID is not being explicitly mentioned using `--project`.

Regarding your issue with the GitHub file, I have checked the repository and the file `storage_blacklist_public.yaml` doesn't seem to be in the directory [`policy-library/samples`](https://github.com/forseti-security/policy-library/tree/master/samples). There seems to be [a trace](https://github.com/forseti-security/policy-library/issues/114#issue-466898017) that it was once there, but it isn't anymore, they should probably update the lab as it isn't anymore.

About your credentials confusion, you don't have to use your own project ID, just the one given on your lab. If I recall properly all the needed data should be on the left side of the lab. Still, you shouldn't need to authenticate in a normal situation as you are already logged in your temporal project if you are accessing it form the Cloud Shell, which is where you should be doing all this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for the later versions

in the gcloud shell you can set a temp variable for the current project id with

`PROJECT_ID="$(gcloud config get-value project)"`

then use like

`--project ${PROJECT_ID}`